# How to set negative part to zero in a MatrixSymbol?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to set negative part to zero in a MatrixSymbol.

```py
from sympy import MatrixSymbol

x = MatrixSymbol('x', 10, 10)
_ = x < 0  # raise TypeError: Invalid comparison of non-real x

# what I want to do:
x[x < 0] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that, because the `MatrixSymbol` API does not provide assigning an element.

Instead, use the `Matrix` API like the following example.

```
from sympy import Symbol, Matrix, Piecewise

m = Matrix(2, 2,
    lambda i, j: Symbol(f'm{i}{j}', real=True)
)
m2 = Matrix(m.rows, m.cols,
    lambda i, j: Piecewise((0, m[i, j] < 0), (m[i, j], True))
)
```

Comment: I have the following error : `File "test.py", line 4
    lambda i, j: Symbol(f'm{i}{j}', real=True)
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: @executable, what version of Python are you using? It works fine on my 3.8.10.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.5, that's why

Comment: @executable, I recommend to use Python 3, because Python 2 is not supported anymore.

Comment: Right, I forgot I already have python 3 installed, I had to use `python3` to execute the program